# VMware Fusion on macOS cannot start .vmx file

Tags: virtualization, vmware

I have VMware Fusion Professional Version 12.1.0 (17195230) installed on macOS Big Sur (11.1).

When starting a fresh new virtual machine (set up ISO to boot from in order to install an OS) I run into the problem that VMware Fusion tells me it cannot open the corresponding **.vmx** file.

So far I have tried to install Linux guest systems (Arch, Gentoo, Debian), system resource on my host system are enough. The **.vmx** file is in place. [This article](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1003748) on VMware's knowledge base was moderately helpful in checking whether the file was okay.

Searching the Internet I haven't found any useful information on how to troubleshot this issue. Could not locate any *vmware.log* file to give me a precise indication what went wrong when trying to start these new virtual machine.

I would be more than happy to hear from you about hints on how to troubleshoot this further.

Comment: The virtual machine specific **vmware.log** _files_ are stored in the virtual machine's _document bundle_.  Locate it in **Finder** and the _right-click_ and select **Show Package Contents**.

Comment: I cannot find any document bundle, neither with Finder nor using a terminal


`ls -a ~/Virtual Machines.localized                                                                                        
total 16
drwxr-xr-x   5 paisquy  staff   160 Jan 21 21:18 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 56 paisquy  staff  1792 Jan 21 21:51 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 paisquy  staff  6148 Jan 21 21:17 .DS_Store
drwxr-xr-x  10 paisquy  staff   320 Nov 17 14:35 .localized
drwxr-xr-x@ 15 paisquy  staff   480 Jan 21 21:49 HEFFTOR-Linux.vmwarevm`

Comment: `ls -al HEFFTOR-Linux.vmwarevm                                                                                                     

HEFFTOR-Linux.plist
HEFFTOR-Linux.vmsd
HEFFTOR-Linux.vmx
HEFFTOR-Linux.vmx.lck
HEFFTOR-Linux.vmxf
Virtuelle Festplatte-s001.vmdk
Virtuelle Festplatte-s002.vmdk
Virtuelle Festplatte-s003.vmdk
Virtuelle Festplatte-s004.vmdk
Virtuelle Festplatte-s005.vmdk
Virtuelle Festplatte-s006.vmdk
Virtuelle Festplatte-s007.vmdk
Virtuelle Festplatte.vmdk
`

Comment: `ls -al HEFFTOR-Linux.vmx.lck                                                                                      
total 8
drwxrwxrwx   3 paisquy  staff   96 Jan 21 21:18 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 15 paisquy  staff  480 Jan 21 21:49 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 paisquy  staff  512 Jan 21 21:18 M03796.lck
`

Comment: I couldn't locate a document bundle, neither with Finder nor in the terminal with the `find` and `locate`commands

Comment: **HEFFTOR-Linux.vmwarevm** is a _document bundle_. If there are no **.log** _files_ in it, then look at the **.log** _files_ for the **VMware Fusion** _application_. You should be able to view them in **Console** or look in `~/Library/Logs/VMware Fusion` at the **vmware-vmfusion.log** _files_.

Comment: I uploaded the log here: [AppDevTools](https://www.appdevtools.com/pastebin/5dVIVA)

Too many lines to paste the output here